# The text document does not save what is written

Tags: c

I was doing a project, where the program would create a file, then it would read this text file and count how many vowels( vogais ) and how many consonants( consoantes ) would have in the word, but the program isn't saving what I write in the text ed document.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *arq;
char c[80];
int consoantes = 0, vogais = 0, i, k;
arq = fopen("arquivoapenas.txt", "a");

if(arq){
printf("informe qualquer coisa ae:\n");
fgets(c, 80, stdin);

}
else{
printf("não foi possivel criar o arquivo\n");
}

system("pause");

arq = fopen("arquivo apenas.txt", "r");

while(fgets(c, 20, arq) != NULL);{
printf("%s\n", c);

}


k = strlen(c);

for( i = 0; i < k; i++){

switch(c[i]){
case 'A':
case 'a':
case 'E':
case 'e':
case 'I':
case 'i':
case 'O':
case 'o':
case 'U':
case 'u':
vogais++;
break;
default:
consoantes++;

}

}
printf("Vogais: %d\n", vogais);
printf("Consoantes: %d\n", consoantes);

fclose(arq);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please point to the code where you think you are writing something to the file. I cannot see any calls to `fwrite`, `write`, `fprintf` or any other file write function.

Comment: Also, be aware that the two `fopen` calls are using different file names.

Comment: You  never write to the first file, nor do you close it.  Instead, you open the second file, saving the file pointer to the same variable and therefore losing the original, which is therefore left open until the program terminates.

Comment: If you want to write to a file, there are three things you should do:  (1) open it for writing/append, (2) write to it, (3) close it.  You're only doing step 1.  And if you need to have two files open simultaneously, then you need to use different variables for the file pointers so you can access them both and close them both.

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(c, 20, arq) != NULL);{`  the semicolon `;` ends the `while` loop so the code inside the following braces `{`...`}` is not executed as part of a loop.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: after this statement: `while(fgets(c, 20, arq) != NULL);` is corrected, then this `while` loop will read all the lines in the input file. before exiting the `while` loop,.  The result is the array `c[]` will only contain the last line in the file

Comment: regarding: `printf("informe qualquer coisa ae:\n");
  fgets(c, 80, stdin);`  The data read from `stdin` into the array `c[]` is never processed because this line:  `while(fgets(c, 20, arq) != NULL);` overlays the contents.

Comment: regarding: `default:
     consoantes++;
     break;`  this is treating any punctuation, `white space`, etc as 'consoantes', which they are not

Comment: OT: the scope of variables should be limited rather than covering the whole file.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int consoantes = 0, vogais = 0, i, k;` please follow the axiom: *only one declaration per statement*.

Comment: regarding: `k = strlen(c);`  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`, so the variable `k` should be declared as `size_t`, not `int`.  Then the `i` variable should also be a `size_t`.

Comment: when  compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (I.E. for `gcc`, at a minimum use options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11)  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the basic functionality
3. is appropriately indented for readability
4. limits the scope of the local variables
5. does not copy the input file to a output file
6. does not handle the possibility of 'y' being a vogais
7. treats all non-vogais as consoantes

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *arq;
    char c[80];
    int consoantes = 0;
    int vogais = 0;
    arq = fopen( "arquivoapenas.txt", "a" );

    if(arq)
    {
        printf( "informe qualquer coisa ae:\n" );
    }
    
    else
    {   // input file failed to open
        // inform user why the 'fopen()' failed
        perror( "fopen to read 'arquivoapenas.txt' failed" );

        printf( "não foi possivel criar o arquivo\n" );
    }

    system( "pause" );

    while( fgets( c, 20, arq ) != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", c );
        fprintf( arq, "%s", c );

        size_t k = strlen( c );

        for( size_t i = 0; i < k; i++ )
        {
            switch(c[i])
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                case 'I':
                case 'i':
                case 'O':
                case 'o':
                case 'U':
                case 'u':
                    vogais++;
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    consoantes++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Vogais: %d\n", vogais);
    printf("Consoantes: %d\n", consoantes);

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```